# Why show Exception this code?

Tags: java, exception, casting

I am studying algorithm with Java and I dont understanding why show error in line 7?

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        int [ ] [ ] a = { {1,2}, {3,4} };
        int [ ] b = (int [ ]) a[1];
        Object o1 = a;
        int [ ] [ ] a2 = (int [ ] [ ]) o1;
        int [ ] b2 = (int [ ]) o1;
        System.out.println(b[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is line 7? What is the error?

Comment: The line is "int [ ] b2 = (int [ ]) o1;" and show >>> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [[I cannot be cast to [I at Test.main(Test.java:7)

Comment: I suggest you add this to the question.  When ever some say "doesn't work" you know some one will ask "what doesn't work" and when some say "an error" someone will ask "what error?" ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am assuming your have a "ClassCastException cannot convert from [[I to [I".  When you get an error you should assume it is important and if you don't know what it means you can usually google it.

The cryptic part here is that internally, the JVM calls `int[]` as `[I` and `int[][]` and `[[I`  The `[` at the start means it is an array and the `I` is short for `int`,  There is also `Z` for boolean, `B` for bytes, `S` for short, `C` for characters, `F` for float, `D` for double and `J` for long. `J` is the letter after `I`.  Built in classes start with `L` and end with `;`  I would have been tempted to make `L` for long and `J` for Java class, but that's just me ;)

You can't do this

```
(int [ ]) o1;
```

because `o1` is actually an `int[][]` not an `int[]` and you can't cast between incompatible types.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Lawrey. I was confused about the type Object.

Comment: @filran this style of cast would work in other languages like C, however Java checks the type at runtime and won't allow this.